# howto loop sed to get variable

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have a CSV file of 15000 rows. From the list I want to delete the unwanted products/manufacturers. I have a list with manufacturers and the source CSV file.

I found that sed would be appropiate but I'm hanging around the loop.

```
while read line
do
    unwanted = $
sed "|"$unwanted|d" /home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv >/home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.c$
done < /home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
```

Any help is appreciated.

Inputfile:

CONSUMABLES;Inktpatronen voor printer;Inkt voor printer;B0137790;HP;Pakket 2 inktpatronen No339 - Zwart + Papier Goodway - 80 g/m² - A4 - 500 vel;Dit pakket van 2 inktpatronen nr 339 zijn ontworpen voor uw HP printer en leveren afdrukken van kwaliteit.;47.19;6.99;47.19;http://pan8.fotovista.com/dev/8/5/32150358/l_32150358.jpg;in stock;0.2;0.11201;9.99;;C9504EE;0;;

Comment: Can you show the contents of the input files and the expected output?

Comment: sounds like typical awk job. but without input/expected output, it is hard to find the start point.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm figuring out which one is best actually..but tnx for the advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that each loop cycle takes the output file from the previous cycle as the input file, otherwise you'll keep overwriting the output file with the content of the original file minus the last unwanted record.

If your `sed` command supports inline editing (option `-i`) you can do this:

```
cp /home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv /home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv
while read line; do
  sed -i "/$line/d" /home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv
done < /home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
```

Otherwise you have to handle the temporary file yourself:

```
cp /home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv /home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv
while read line; do
  sed "/$line/d" /home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv >/home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.c$
  mv -f /home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.c$ /home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv
done < /home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
```

Comment: tnx..someting like that i figured out also.. works nice.. In the meantime I hit the nxt stop..

Comment: while read line; do
sed --in-place "/$line/d" /home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv
done < /home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
this is what i came up with.. it works flawless..

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `sed` in two steps:

1. Create the `sed` script from the unwanted information.
2. Apply the created script to the data file.

That might be:

```
unwanted=/home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
datafile=/home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv
cleaned=/home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv

sed 's%.*%/,&,/d%' $unwanted > sed.script
sed -f sed.script  $datafile > $cleaned

rm -f sed.script
```

The first invocation of `sed` simply replace the contents of each line describing unwanted records with a `sed` command that will delete it as a comma-separated field in the middle of an data line.  If you have to handle unwanted fields at the beginning or the end too, then you have to work harder.  You also have to work harder if there might be embedded slashes, commas, quotes etc.  The second invocation of `sed` applies the script created by the first to the data file, generating the cleaned file.

You can improve it by ensuring the script file name is unique, and by trapping the script file if the process is interrupted:

```
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/script.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15 # EXIT, HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE, TERM

unwanted=/home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
datafile=/home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv
cleaned=/home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv

sed 's%.*%/,&,/d%' $unwanted > $tmp
sed -f $tmp $datafile > $cleaned

rm -f $tmp
trap 0  # Cancel the exit trap
```

With GNU `sed`, but not with Mac OS X (BSD) `sed`, you could avoid the intermediate file thus:

```
unwanted=/home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
datafile=/home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv
cleaned=/home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv

sed 's%.*%/,&,/d%' $unwanted |
sed -f - $datafile > $cleaned
```

This tells the second `sed` to read its script from standard input.  If you have `bash` version 4.x (not standard on Mac OS X), you could use process substitution instead:

```
unwanted=/home/bankey/shopimport/unwanted.txt
datafile=/home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv
cleaned=/home/arno/pixtmp/pix-clean.csv

sed -f <(sed 's%.*%/,&,/d%' $unwanted) $datafile > $cleaned
```

Comment: hmm..i think i will rewrite the script and put these lines in.. very sweet.. tnx..

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is less suited than `awk`.  For example, assuming your input file and your list of undesired terms are space delimited, you could simply do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]++ } NR != FNR && !a[$1]' undesired input
```

This will print out the file 'input' file, omitting any line in which the first column matches a line in the file `undesired`.